# Analysis of categorical variables with different levels - R programming

Tags: r, python

Dataframe shows different levels for each of the fields Sex:2, Color:4, Geography:3, ID:8. For this analysis let us assume Sex, Colors, ID, Geography are the only variables of interest and contains all the information.

Question1: I need to understand how Sex, Color and ID are related to Geography ?

Question2: How do we compute correlation matrix for the data frame. I know Pearson Correlation cannot be computed. Is it possible to compute Chi-square correlation or any other type of correlation among variables ?

The general question I have is how do you work with variables having different number of levels. Any good reference would help. I read the book ISLR but says it is beyond the scope of this book. Thanks!

[image: survey_table]

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to predict the value of Geography from Sex and Color? Or to understand how Sex and Color affect Geography (e.g., the effect of Color on Geography may be different for each Sex). Are Sex and Colors the only independent variables of interest?

It looks like these variables were measured on some type of birds. Were the birds of the same species or of different species?

Furthermore, were the birds located at the same site or at different sites? Were the birds monitored during a single day/season/year or over multiple days/seasons/years?

The statistical model you will use will have to factor in information about the study design and the research question(s) you are interested in. You have not provided enough details about your study design and research questions, but if you try to address the questions I mentioned above, you should get a better handle on how you need to proceed. At that stage, you can edit your question to fill in the missing details so that you can receive meaningful answers.